# Flex: Where is the default skin class located/specified (for components like ComboBox)

Tags: apache-flex, coding-style

For example the spark `ComboBox`.

- Where is the default skin?
- Is it generated (at compile or runtime)?
- If it was in fact written by someone how does the compiler/Virtual Machine know where to find the skin class?  I didn't see a location specified in the ComboBox source.

Thanks!

*Edit: Sorry originally meant to say skin by typed style instead*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark components use mostly skins. The default skin is defined in the `defaults.css` file which gets compiled into the `spark.swc`. The CSS for `ComboBox` looks like this:

```
ComboBox
{
/*  dropShadowVisible: true; in spark.css */
    paddingBottom: 3;
    paddingLeft: 3;
    paddingRight: 3;
    paddingTop: 5;
    skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.spark.ComboBoxSkin");
}
```

So, the class `spark.skins.spark.ComboBoxSkin` is defined as default skin for `ComboBox`. You can find the complete file in your Flex SDK (`frameworks/projects/spark/defaults.css`).

If you want to find out more about this take a look at the following topics on Adobe Flex Help:

- [About Spark
  skins](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSC8DB0C28-F7A6-48ff-9899-7957415A0A49.html)
- [Applying styles from a defaults.css file](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf68cf9-7ffe.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a00)